# Spring Batch: How exactly does job restarting work regarding executions and context?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch

So I have a simple batch job with just one step which consists of a MongoItemReader to read in objects from MongoDB of course, a custom item processor (which for now just sets an 'isProcessed' boolean flag to true), and a MongoItemWriter.

Thing is, I want to be able to backup my jobs to a DB whenever they fail (for cases like server downtime), so I have implemented Mongo documents that basically store `JobExecution`, `StepExecution`, `JobInstance`, and `ExecutionContext` objects. They seem to create their respective objects correctly since I am able to use them to restart a job (after adding them to the job repository), but they are restarting from the very beginning when I instead want them to start from where they left off.

So I'm wondering then what I'm missing. Where exactly does a failed job store data of when/where it failed? I thought the `readCount`, `readSkipCount`, `processSkipCount`, etc variables would have something to do with it, but those are included in my `StepExecution` document (along with everything else the `StepExecution` class has a 'get' method for). I thought then maybe it was the execution context, but that was empty for both the job and its one step.

Answer (score 0):

When a job is restarted, stateful components (those that implement `ItemStream`) receive the step's `ExecutionContext` during the open call allowing them to reset the state based on the last run.  It's then up to the component to reset the state as well as maintain the state during the calls to `ItemStream#update` as processing occurs.

So based on the above, a failed job doesn't persist it's state when it fails...it's actually persisting it all along as it's successful.  That way, when it does fail, things should be rolled back to the last successful point.  Which leads me to...

Mongo isn't transactional.  Are you sure the state is being persisted correctly?  We don't have a Mongo based job repository for this reason...

Comment: I see, that clears some things up, but where exactly then is the 'state' stored? In the `ExecutionContext`? Yes I understand Mongo isn't transactional, but the `MongoItemReader` is paginated right? When I restart a failed job, should it not restart from or after the page that it last had success with? So obviously from my questions I'm not sure if state is being persisted correctly haha. When I recreate the execution objects from the Mongo documents, they have the correct statuses, but their execution context's contain no entries (they had none when I saved them on completion).

Comment: Correct.  The state is stored in the `ExecutionContext`.  It's normally stored as JSON so it's human readable.

Comment: Ok, so then in my case when I'm getting empty `ExecutionContext` objects and the end of my job failing, is that possibly because it's getting the context from the last failed chunk? That is, if I were somehow to look at the `ExecutionContext` objects for successful chunks, those objects wouldn't be empty?

Comment: Also, I thought of a workaround which is to have my `MongoItemReader` query for only objects that have my 'isProcessed' flag set to true, but for some odd reason, every single time, the reader only reads in half of the number of objects that the query should return. Stranger even is that its not always exactly half: if the half is not of my chunk size, it rounds up. (e.g. chunk size = 100 and 500 objects should be returned by query, but it only reads 300 rounding up from 250 apparently)